# Column validation in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have reffered http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/unique-validation-on-composite-fields-in-sharepoint.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("PreSaveAction");
function PreSaveAction(){

var userName = $(":input[title='drnt']").val();
   var phoneVal = $(":input[title='bson']").val();
   var itemId = getParameterByName("ID");
   if (itemId == "")
      itemId = 0;

 var lstItemCount = 0;
   if (userName !== null && userName !== "" && phoneVal
        !== null && phoneVal !== "")
   {
      var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
           "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('UserInformation')/items?$filter=((Username eq '" + userName + "')and (PhoneNumber eq '" + phoneVal + "') and (Id ne " + itemId + "))";
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: siteUrl,
        async: false,
        method: "get",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
           lstItemCount = data.d.results.length;
     },
     error: function (data) {
        $("#errorMsg").text("ERROR: Request failed");
        $("#errorMsg").css({ display: "block" });
        return false;
     }
  });
 if(lstItemCount > 0)
  {
     $("#errorMsg").text("ERROR: Item Already Exists");
     $("#errorMsg").css({ display: "block" });
     return false;
  }
  else
  {
     return true;
  }


}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<style>
 .error-message {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #EC9290;
    color: #EC9290;
 }
 </style>
 <div id="errorMsg" class="error-message"></div>
```

I used this code so that the column should not take duplicate value. it shows error at getParameterByName that it doesnt exist and also username and phoneval value is undefined.

Comment: try `$("input[title='drnt']")` and `$("input[title='bson']")`

Comment: this is also undefined